# Simple Convolutional Neural Network can't reduce it's cost

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I made my first CNN using tensorflow. The objective is to recognize if there is a dog or a cat in a black-white photo with 100x100 pixels.
The problem is a strange behavior/output from the neural net. The first output is Ok, but others are too extreme. I think the Raw Output (last values before softmax) maybe is too high. But i can't find a way to decrease it.
What I already tried without success:

- Change weights and bias from random_normal to ones and zeros
- Decrease a lot the learning rate
- Use tf.image.per_image_standardization()

**My Code:**

```
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os, random

nClasses = 2
iHeight = 100
iWidth = 100

ds=[]


w = {
    "w1": tf.Variable(tf.ones([5,5,1,32],dtype=float)),
    "w2": tf.Variable(tf.ones([5,5,32,64],dtype=float)),
    "w3": tf.Variable(tf.ones([90*90*64,50],dtype=float)),
    "w4": tf.Variable(tf.ones([50,2],dtype=float)),


}

b = {
        "b1": tf.Variable(tf.zeros([32], dtype=float)),
        "b2": tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64], dtype=float)),
        "b3": tf.Variable(tf.zeros([50], dtype=float)),
        "b4": tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2], dtype=float)),

}


def loadImage(path):
    img = Image.open(path)
    data = np.asarray(img,dtype=float)
    return data



for file in os.listdir("dataset/cat/"):
    ds.append({"input":loadImage("dataset/cat/"+file), "output":np.array([[1,0]],dtype=float)})

for file in os.listdir("dataset/dog/"):
    ds.append({"input":loadImage("dataset/dog/"+file), "output":np.array([[0,1]],dtype=float)})

rawInput = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [iWidth, iHeight], name="input")
output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nClasses], name="iClass")

input = tf.reshape(rawInput, [-1,100,100,1])

#First convolution and pooling
conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input, w["w1"], strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="VALID")
conv1_b = tf.nn.bias_add(conv1, b["b1"])
conv1_a = tf.nn.relu(conv1_b)

pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1_a,[1,2,2,1],strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = "VALID")

#Second convolution and pooling
conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, w["w2"], strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="VALID")
conv2_b = tf.nn.bias_add(conv2, b["b2"])
conv2_a = tf.nn.relu(conv2_b)

pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2_a,[1,2,2,1],strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = "VALID")

#Transforming to the first fully connected layer
pool2_fcl = tf.reshape(pool2,[1, 90*90*64])
fcl1=tf.matmul(pool2_fcl,w["w3"])
fcl1_b=tf.nn.bias_add(fcl1,b["b3"])
fcl1_a=tf.nn.relu(fcl1_b)


#Second fully connected layer
fcl2=tf.matmul(fcl1,w["w4"])
fcl2_b =tf.nn.bias_add(fcl2,b["b4"])
pred= tf.nn.softmax(fcl2_b)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=fcl2_b,labels=output))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for x in range (100):
        y = random.randint(0,len(ds)-1)
        optimizerVal,rawOutput, predVal,labelVal,costVal = sess.run([optimizer,fcl2_b,pred,output,cost],feed_dict={rawInput:ds[y]["input"], output:ds[y]["output"]})
        print("Raw Output (fcl2_b): %s\nPred: %s\nLabel: %s\nCost:%s\n\n"%(rawOutput, predVal,labelVal,costVal))
    print(b["b1"].eval())
```

**Output:**

> Raw Output (fcl2_b): [[1.0071293e+14 1.0071293e+14]] 
>   Pred: [[0.5 0.5]]
>   Label: [[1. 0.]] 
>   Cost:0.6931472
>
> Raw Output (fcl2_b): [[1.0680586e+14 1.0680579e+14]] Pred: [[1. 0.]]
>   Label: [[1. 0.]] Cost:0.0
>
> Raw Output (fcl2_b): [[6.8944283e+13 6.8944161e+13]] Pred: [[1. 0.]]
>   Label: [[0. 1.]] Cost:121634820.0
>
> Raw Output (fcl2_b): [[5.6959584e+13 5.6959487e+13]] Pred: [[1. 0.]]
>   Label: [[1. 0.]] Cost:0.0
>
> Raw Output (fcl2_b): [[8.481456e+13 8.481446e+13]] Pred: [[1. 0.]]
>   Label: [[0. 1.]] Cost:92274690.0

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you using `fcl2_b` as logits and not `pred`?

Comment: Yes, it's not recommended to use data after normalization (softmax) in the logit parameter.

Comment: Not recommended? I'm not sure where you got that from.

Comment: fcl2_b are actual logits, pred doesn't contain logits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the weight initialisation:

`tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32]), dtype=tf.float32)`

The biases are fine, but you should 'symmetry break' the weights. See for example [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22093/why-should-the-initialization-of-weights-and-bias-be-chosen-around-0).

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot! I used: tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32],dtype=tf.float32,stddev=0.1)

The major problem was equal or too high initial weights.
The model still don't converge to the global minima, but at least there is no more extreme predictions.